# chrome.storage.local.get returns undefined during browser startup, but only for a specific value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension, and inside the background script during browser startup I try to get stored variables to update the extension. This works fine the first time, however once I get the variables I then call a networking script, and when that file tries to get a variable it stops working.

Background script:

```js
chrome.storage.local.get(["accessToken", "fileId", "date"], (result) => {
            if(result.accessToken && result.fileId && result.date) {
                axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + result.accessToken;

                getLastChanged(result.fileId)
                    .then(date => {
                        if(date !== result.date) {
                            getFile(result.fileId)
                                .then(file => {
                                    chrome.storage.local.set({links:file, date:date});
                                });
                        }
                    })
        });
```

Networking Script:

```js
 chrome.storage.local.get(["refreshToken"], (result) => {
                if(result.refreshToken){
                    axios.post("https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token", {
                        refresh_token:result.refreshToken,
                        client_id:clientId.installed.client_id,
                        client_secret:clientId.installed.client_secret,
                        grant_type:"refresh_token"
                    }).then(res => {
                        axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + res.data.accessToken;
                        chrome.storage.local.set({accessToken:res.data.access_token});
                        resolve();
                    }).catch(err => reject(err));
                }

                reject("no refresh token");
            });
```

The background script is able to get those three values just fine, but when the networking script tries to get the refresh token it returns undefined. When I check local storage the refresh token is there, and when I open the extension window I run this exact same networking script to check that is it up to date, and it works fine. It is only during browser startup, and only with this one value that is fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You better access the localStorage from the background script rather than content script directly. Either use `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage` to get background script, and then access the storage, or send a message to `background_script` to get the value you need, and return it back to your content ("network") script. 
As  @wOxxOm suggested turn **persistent: false** for the background script

Comment: So only the background.js file has rights to access storage, even if the background file calls it? Thanks! I'll modify it so it also passes the refresh token.

Comment: For consistency I suggest to use the above. As you can learn from documentation you do have access from content script , but from my experience it has flaws and not consistent. You can read more here https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage

Comment: At the time the extension runs he can check for user in localstorage. Have done that in dozens of projects

Comment: @Zach will you share your code online? Will be happy to assist with the full working solution

Comment: Found more info at https://crbug.com/314686#c6 - a persistent background script won't be started but an event page will be, which probably explains why the OP encountered the problem while Yuvals didn't.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused by the fact that during startup Chrome starts the active web page and its content scripts before it starts the extension's **persistent** background page (declared without `"persistent": false` in manifest.json), see [crbug.com/314686](https://crbug.com/314686) and [crbug.com/767844](https://crbug.com/767844).

You can wait until the background page sets the value:

```
readOrWaitStorage('refreshToken').then(refreshToken => {
  axios.post('https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token', {
    refresh_token: refreshToken,
    // ......................
  });
});

function readOrWaitStorage(key) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    chrome.storage.local.get(key, data => {
      if (key in data) {
        resolve(data[key]);
        return;
      }
      chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(function fn(changes) {
        if (key in changes) {
          chrome.storage.onChanged.removeListener(fn);
          resolve(changes[key].newValue);
        }
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Or you can switch to `"persistent": false` background script and use messaging.

Comment: Therefore, he can run this in background script. Saying “worng” on sonething wont make it wrong

Comment: @Yuvals, you don't seem to be in a reasonable mood but I'll try to explain again anyway: the OP's problem is a known peculiarity of Chrome's startup process as explained in the linked crbug ticket and this is not related to localStorage or any other storage. This answer shows one of the possible correct solutions of the problem. Yours didn't.

Comment: Also, reported @Yuvals for revenge downvoting.

Comment: Your edited answer is clearly better.. so it is possible to use background script after all... voting up

Comment: I just found out the additional dependence on the type of the background script myself. You can also mention this distinction in your answer and suggest the OP to switch the background script type so they would use messaging as you suggested. So that both our answers will be technically correct and potentially useful for different use cases.

Comment: I also retracted the flag. Sorry for misjudging you.

Comment: Thank you. Same here. Will also appreciate unvoting down